# System Tray Icon Double / Single Click Issue

Tags: c#, .net, system-tray

I created System Tray Icon and added two click Events Double Click, Single Click. i tried mouse click and normal both click.

```
    SysTray.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(SysTray_MouseClick);
    SysTray.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseEventHandler(SysTray_MouseDoubleClick);

    void SysTray_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        SingleClick = true;

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300);
            if (SingleClick)
            {
                //To Do
            }
        }
    }

    void SysTray_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            SingleClick = false;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
            //To Do 
        }
    }
```

If I Double Click on System Tray Icon it will automatic execute Single Click Icon.

how can i ractify double / single click issue

Comment: A double-click *always* starts with a single click first.  If the user clicks fast enough then the 2nd click turns into a double click.  You will need to accommodate this in your UI design.  A silly trick is to start a Timer in the MouseClick event.  Stop the timer in the double click event handler, use the Tick event to do a single click action.  This however works poorly because the user won't understand why his click is so sluggish to respond.  Use a context menu instead.

Answer (score 5):

I know it's been a while, but I just solved this using a timer:

```
Timer singleClickTimer = new Timer();

private void trayIcon_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        // Give the double-click a chance to cancel this
        singleClickTimer.Interval = (int) (SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime * 1.1);
        singleClickTimer.Start();
    }
}

private void singleClickTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    singleClickTimer.Stop();

    // do single click here
}

private void trayIcon_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        // Cancel the single click
        singleClickTimer.Stop();

        // do double click here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like hans said in comment. Double click always start with singleclick. So I present you one of my solution

In your class , create a boolean.

```
 bool click=false;
```

Then for the method.

```
 void SysTray_MouseClick(object sender, EventArge e)
     {
        click=true;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300);//Test with this amount!!
        if(click)
          {
            //codes go here
          }
     }
 void Systray_DoubleClick(object sender , EventArge e)
     {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);//This too!
        click=false; // If it is doubleclick cancel the single click event.
        //codes go here.
     }
```

The main concept is if it is doubleclick cancel the single click event. I run a stopwatch and doubleclick should take 200-350 ms. So adjust the timeing you want. But on the other hand. More timing = the slower your code process

Edit:This logic burst my head!! I end up with this code , try it.

Comment: void SysTray_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            SingleClick = true;

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

            if (SingleClick && e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                // Code
            }
        }

        void SysTray_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            SingleClick = false;

            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                //Code
            }
        }

Comment: How it's not working and please put above code into edit your question. Also 1000 is too much. You'll want it around 200-350 trust me.

Comment: i tried 100 to 1000 ms but every time its execute single click then double click

Comment: @KalpeshChhatrala see my new edit , sorry , that time is my bedtime

Comment: I updated my code in question but still its not working

Comment: Note that there is a system preference for double-click time. Don't hardcode magic values that users might configure differently (especially elderly people often have trouble double-clicking reliably and thus raise that value).

Comment: i tried various value from 100 to 5000 ms seconds but still its not working.